# Prevent radio widgets from rendering labels with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this form element I want to render without a label, but I can't find the way...

```
$builder
    ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'expanded'   => true,
        'choices'    => array(
            'Male' => 'm',
            'Female' => 'f',
            )
        ))
;
```

some help please, this isn't working:

```
{% block choice_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for child in form %}
            <input type="radio" value="{{ child.get('value') }}">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

I'm getting `Array to string conversion`

What I wanna do is an image based gender selector, just clicking an image to make the selection.

Comment: I'm thinking now that I could render just the label to load an image inside and to hide the input. But I have the same problem, how can I hide just the input and to show the label?

Comment: How do you render your form view ? Can you paste the twig code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the form component, do not ever render form fields yourself, always rely on the `form_` helpers as described in the [form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand).

In your case, this should work:

```
{{ form_label(form.gender) }}
{{ form_errors(form.gender) }}

{% for choiceFormView in form.gender %}
    {{ form_widget(choiceFormView) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: use `form_label` instead of `form_widget` in the for loop

Comment: I used this, but instead of seeing radio buttons, it shows the options as drop down box?? how can I use radio buttons?

Comment: @AdrienBrault I'm trying to customize the html for the label when it is a widget label as opposed to the row label. How can I differentiate between the two? I.e., how do I recognise the label is for a radio button and not for a general form row?