# using radio button with FosUser Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to use radio button..

> x Male x Female

I know i can use dropdown box, checkbox etc, but i need to use radio button based on my specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374603/prevent-radio-widgets-from-rendering-labels-with-symfony2).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that radio field type doesn't allow me to use two options. ( At least i couldn't figure out to have two radio buttons ;  xMale xFemale. What is the syntax to be used to have multiple radio buttons?

Comment: True, you can customize your choice widget, I have updated the answer with a SO link.

Comment: i understand the logic you have recommended.. However, I am very new to symfony and fosuser.. I am trying to override the registration page (so that i can use a radio button. However I am not sure how to override the registration page. if you have time, can you take a look at this question.. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557104/how-to-override-the-layout-of-the-fosuser-registration-form-layout[/link]